# Issues writing query that locates a part of a string

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to write a query that will search a list of strings in my database. All the strings are in the same format - below is an example of some of the strings

```
LP-01-MG-01
LN-01-MG-02
LP-02-MG-01
LP-02-MG-04
```

Each dash represents a different part of the string. I need to find all the different results for the last number sequence of these strings. For example with the 4 listed above, would need to return 01, 02 and 04. I have been unable to do this with using the like command and underscores for individual character wildcards or a % at the end for anything after. Anyone have any suggestions? Thanks.

edit - all of the items have a few words after the number sequence as well, not sure if this will matter for any way anyone can solve this issue.

Comment: just a standard sql database on microsoft sql manager - using it with a asp.net application through connection string. I need to generate a list of the last number sequence to fill a drop down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all of them have only two digits following the last hyphen, you can use a combination of the standard SQL `RIGHT()` and `LEFT()` function, available in most RDBMS packages.

```
SELECT RIGHT(LEFT(columnname, 11), 2) AS num FROM tbl;
```

If you don't want duplicates, use `DISTINCT`

```
SELECT DISTINCT RIGHT(LEFT(columnname, 11), 2) AS num FROM tbl;
```

Also possible, and perhaps clearer, with `SUBSTRING()`

```
SELECT DISTINCT SUBSTRING(columnname, 10, 2) AS num FROM tbl;
```

Comment: sorry, just made an edit, they all have text after them as well, only way i can think of is to do it on the vb side to cut the string, but I was wondering if there was anyway to do that in my stored procedure instead, since it would be quicker

Comment: @njj56 See my change above then.  An extra function call to `LEFT()` will do it

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @S VARCHAR(100)
SET @S = 'LP-01-MG-01'

SELECT  RIGHT(@S, CHARINDEX('-', REVERSE(@S)) - 1)
```